# ListView flickering when swapping two datamodels in its source

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

I'm working on a custom sort method that lets the user simply move the selected item up or down, one position at a time.
I do this by animating the two target ListView containers, then swapping the two datamodels in the source collection of the ListView (I'm using an ObservableCollection) and then animating back in the two containers.

It looks something like this:

```
// Fade the containers out
ListViewItem targetContainer = MyListView.ContainerFromIndex(target).Cast<ListViewItem>();
ListViewItem currentContainer = MyListView.ContainerFromIndex(index).Cast<ListViewItem>();

// Just some method to programmatically create animations
Storyboard targetOut = targetContainer.GetFadeSlideStoryboard(TranslationAxis.X, 1, 0, 0, 20, 150);
Storyboard currentOut = currentContainer.GetFadeSlideStoryboard(TranslationAxis.X, 1, 0, 0, -20, 150);

// WaitAsync creates a task that completes when the Storyboard completes
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task> { targetOut.WaitAsync(), currentOut.WaitAsync() };
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// Switch the models
FieldModel swapped = ViewModel.Source[target];
ViewModel.Source[target] = field;
ViewModel.Source[index] = swapped;

// Fade the containers back in
targetContainer = FieldsList.ContainerFromIndex(target).Cast<ListViewItem>();
currentContainer = FieldsList.ContainerFromIndex(index).Cast<ListViewItem>();
targetOut = targetContainer.StartFadeSlideStoryboard(TranslationAxis.X, 0, 1, -20, 0, 150);
currentOut = currentContainer.StartFadeSlideStoryboard(TranslationAxis.X, 0, 1, 20, 0, 150);
```

It works fine, the only problem is that I thought the ListView would reuse the two visual containers, but instead it looks like it's rendering the two DataTemplates again.

I mean, there is a fraction of a second, right when I assign the first swapped DataModel, where the target DataTemplate disappear and the reappear back again with the new DataModel I just assigned.

It really happens in a blink of an eye, but this causes the whole ListView control to slide up and then back down as soon as the new DataTemplate is rendered.

Is there a way to just assign the two DataModels directly into the DataTemplates and have these changes reflect in my source collection?
This way the ListView wouldn't render those containers again.

Thank you for your help!

Sergio

Comment: Does the flicker happen if you just change the data of list rather than swapping in a new instance?

Comment: Well if I change the source collection the listview actually reloads all its content, and that's not what I'm trying to do here. I mean, if I do that it also plays the animations etc... I just want to swap two containers/DataModels

Comment: How about getting the items to be swapped from the ViewModel.Source then manually updating their properties. This way if the Models implement the IPropertyChanged interface it should make the ListView update the items without re-rendering the entire DataTemplate again.